# powerpoint breaking links via excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am trying to update a PowerPoint Presentation with embedded charts via Excel by using a VBA script. This works fine with my code. The Problem is that I also want - after the charts have been updated - to break/remove the links to the Excle worksheet.

The code example shows my code also with the line that doesn´t work.

Any suggestion or solution would be highly appreciated!

```
Function RefreshPPT()
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open "Name.pptx", Untitled:=msoTrue
PPT.ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
PPT.ActivePresentation.BreakLinks ------ this line doesn´t work
PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs Filename:="Name2.pptx"
PPT.Quit
Set PPT = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Does the compiler autocomplete the .BreakLinks command when you type it? Have you activated the powerpoint Reference in this project (Microsoft Powerpoint xx.x Object Library)? The latter is sometimes forgotten as a lot of the functionality is also in the Office library, but not all...

Comment: Yes, it is autocompleted. But there is a failure message during execution regarding this line. The Powerpoint reference is also activated.

Comment: Can you please also post the failure message in your question. To know the exact problem enables the community to solve it!

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the answers.

I think I have solved the problem: The syntax of the breakline command was wrong. 
I had to address the slides and shapes directly:

```
PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(s).LinkFormat.BreakLink
```